# How to return Vector3 in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to write function which will return vector3.

```
public Vector3 returnVec(){
    //Some code
    return gameObject.transform.position;
}
```

And I want to call this function from another script but I getting error:
"not all code paths return a value"

Can you help me?

Comment: How about posting the *complete* function body? Presumably, your error is in "Some code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error states that you miss a `return` somewhere, in the block that you commented out as "Some code". You have some if cases for sure, there, and some execution path does not end with a `return`.

Something like:

```
if (A){
   //return a Vector3;
else if (B){
   //instructions without a return;
   //end of method;
}
```